# React-native: How do i pass parameters to Stacknavigator component

Tags: javascript, react-native, parameters, navigation

I'm using Stack Navigator.
I wonder how do i pass parameter to it.

The index.js file i render Pick Component

```
render() {
    return (
        ...
           <Pick>
        ...
    );
}
```

pick.js component is a stack navigator

```
class PickCategory extends React.Component 
{
    ....
}

module.exports = StackNavigator({
    Parent: { screen: PickCategory },
})
```

How do i pass parameter from index.js to pick.js to use it inside PickCategory ?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `screenProps` via the stack navigator. You would need a bit of restructuring like so:

```
const PickerNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Parent: { screen: PickCategory }
});

class Picker extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <PickerNavigator screenProps={...your props...} />;
  }
}
```

Your props would then be accessible in `PickerCategory` via `this.props.screenProps`.

Comment: Didn't work. I've tried it before `<PickCategory screenProps={{abc:'abc'}} />` , and inside PickCategory constructor: `alert(this.props.screenProps)` ~> `Cannot read property `screenProps` of undefined`

Comment: Inside the constructor `props` will come from the function argument. So: `constructor(props) { super(props); console.log(props.screenProps); }`